# Center img in the div block (slick-slider)

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I have a proplem with center `img` in the `div`. I read and doing all answers in the questions about center align. And `display: flex` help me, but it doing my `slick-slider` jumping. 3 screen it seems good and next jump with no slides 1 second and next good. You can see it in my [site](http://test.aleksandernitchenko.ru/). How can i centralize my `img` in the `div` without `flex` and `position: absolute`? Or how can I doing that without jump slider? I hope guys, you understand my English, and sorry for that simple question...

```css
    div {
      display: flex!important;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      outline: none;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      img{
        width: 50%;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="partners multiple-items">
         <div>
            <img src="img/logo-adata.png">
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please provide code snippet or a fiddle

Comment: I'm add snippet code. You can see jumping of slide if you 3-click right-arrow on down slider in my site

Comment: Well, I tried this solution directly on your website: I removed `justify-content: center;` from `.partners div` and add  `margin: 0 auto;` to `.slick-slide img` and the slide seems work well, but you must continue to use flexbox to center them vertically and I don't know if this is a problem for you.

Comment: @ReSedano, it's really work. I try do it early, but I hav't success. Thank you

Comment: Mistery of the web! You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
  display: flex!important;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 65%;
  }
}
```

It's solve my problem & slider don't jump

Comment: I have bug with this method. First download site, width of slick elements = 0
Need use standart slick display: block with no this trouble

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

```css
.partners
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.item{
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="partners multiple-items">
     <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm write in .scss preprocessor

Comment: ah okay i changed the answer with margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I edited the code, try to use display: table-cell; and vertical-align: middle

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the `img` tag?

One way to achieve this is to use `background-image` instead of `img.` Simple remove the `img` tag, then you can `center` the image as

```
.img__wrapper {
  background-image: url(img/news-img-1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is how it can be done *with* the `img` tag

```
.img__wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.img__wrapper > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm need ability to change img in site admin-panel

Comment: Why can't you use `position: absolute` on the `img` tag? It doesn't *jump* for me.

Comment: Couse div lose own width and height with position absolute

Comment: Have you tried to set the `height` to `100%`? I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.partners div{
height:500px;width:500px;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: div.partners div{height:500px;width:500px;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;} Obviously that's using px instead of % but maybe explore display:table-cell - https://jsfiddle.net/kdrysdale/Ljyhtwq8/13/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.